# python OWLReady2 ontology cannot execute the code getting access denied error

Tags: owl, ontology, access-denied, owlready, reasoner

I am trying to execute ontology code which is mentioned in the documentation https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reasoning.html . I have also mentioned the Java path for the reasoner part but still I am getting access denied error. Since I am a beginner in this domain could you please help me where I am going wrong.

Code:

```
from owlready2 import *
import owlready2
owlready2.JAVA_EXE = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19\\bin"

from owlready2 import *

onto = get_ontology("http://test.org/onto.owl")

with onto:
    class Drug(Thing):
        def take(self): print("I took a drug")
    class ActivePrinciple(Thing):
         pass

    class has_for_active_principle(Drug >> ActivePrinciple):
         python_name = "active_principles"

    class Placebo(Drug):
        equivalent_to = [Drug & Not(has_for_active_principle.some(ActivePrinciple))]
        def take(self): print("I took a placebo")

    class SingleActivePrincipleDrug(Drug):
        equivalent_to = [Drug & has_for_active_principle.exactly(1, ActivePrinciple)]
        def take(self): print("I took a drug with a single active principle")

    class DrugAssociation(Drug):
        equivalent_to = [Drug & has_for_active_principle.min(2, ActivePrinciple)]
        def take(self): print("I took a drug with %s active principles" % len(self.active_principles))

acetaminophen   = ActivePrinciple("acetaminophen")
amoxicillin     = ActivePrinciple("amoxicillin")
clavulanic_acid = ActivePrinciple("clavulanic_acid")

AllDifferent([acetaminophen, amoxicillin, clavulanic_acid])

drug1 = Drug(active_principles = [acetaminophen])
drug2 = Drug(active_principles = [amoxicillin, clavulanic_acid])
drug3 = Drug(active_principles = [])

close_world(Drug)

sync_reasoner()`
```

[[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH3AQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq6OO.png)

Not sure why I am getting access denied error after using sync_reasoner() it has to check the consistency of class and reassign but I am getting error

Answer (score 0):

`owlready2.JAVA_EXE` should be set to the path to the Java executable (`java.exe`), not to the directory containing it. See [Configuration](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reasoning.html#configuration) in the Owlready2 documentation.